# How do you close a Java GUI without ending the JVM

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

and no... system.exit(0) is NOT what I am looking for.

I have a MainPage GUI with 5 buttons, clicking 4 of the buttons brings up separate GUI's for different things, one open a chat server, one opens a file dialog, ETC. however, if I use system.exit(0); to close this new GUI it also closes the MainPage GUI and that is not what I want. I have looked into this.dispose(); however I am not sure how to use it.

```
    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0); // this is the same thing as system.exit(0);
        }
    });
    exit.setBounds(BUTTON_INDENT, 4 * BUTTON_HEIGHT + 5 * BUTTON_INDENT,
            BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
```

The point is for this to only close the Maximized GUI and NOT the minimized ones as well.

EDIT:

```
class MyClient implements ActionListener {
Socket s;
DataInputStream dis;
DataOutputStream dos;

JButton sendButton, logoutButton, loginButton, exitButton;
JFrame chatWindow;
JTextArea txtBroadcast;
JTextArea txtMessage;
JList usersList;

// ////////////////////////
public void displayGUI() {
    chatWindow = new JFrame();
    txtBroadcast = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    txtBroadcast.setEditable(false);
    txtMessage = new JTextArea(2, 20);
    usersList = new JList();

    sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    logoutButton = new JButton("Log out");
    loginButton = new JButton("Log in");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    JPanel center1 = new JPanel();
    center1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    center1.add(new JLabel("Broad Cast messages from all online users",
            JLabel.CENTER), "North");
    center1.add(new JScrollPane(txtBroadcast), "Center");

    JPanel south1 = new JPanel();
    south1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    south1.add(new JScrollPane(txtMessage));
    south1.add(sendButton);

    JPanel south2 = new JPanel();
    south2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    south2.add(loginButton);
    south2.add(logoutButton);
    south2.add(exitButton);

    JPanel south = new JPanel();
    south.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    south.add(south1);
    south.add(south2);

    JPanel east = new JPanel();
    east.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    east.add(new JLabel("Online Users", JLabel.CENTER), "East");
    east.add(new JScrollPane(usersList), "South");

    chatWindow.add(east, "East");

    chatWindow.add(center1, "Center");
    chatWindow.add(south, "South");

    chatWindow.pack();
    chatWindow.setTitle("Login for Chat");
    chatWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    chatWindow.setVisible(true);
    sendButton.addActionListener(this);
    logoutButton.addActionListener(this);
    loginButton.addActionListener(this);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
    loginButton.setEnabled(true);
    txtMessage.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
            txtMessage.selectAll();
        }
    });

    chatWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            if (s != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chatWindow,
                        "u r logged out right now. ", "Exit",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                logoutSession();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

// /////////////////////////
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    JButton temp = (JButton) ev.getSource();
    if (temp == sendButton) {
        if (s == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chatWindow,
                    "u r not logged in. plz login first");
            return;
        }
        try {
            dos.writeUTF(txtMessage.getText());
            txtMessage.setText("");
        } catch (Exception excp) {
            txtBroadcast.append("\nsend button click :" + excp);
        }
    }
    if (temp == loginButton) {
        String uname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(chatWindow,
                "Enter Your lovely nick name: ");
        if (uname != null)
            clientChat(uname);
    }
    if (temp == logoutButton) {
        if (s != null)
            logoutSession();
    }
    if (temp == exitButton) {
        if (s != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chatWindow,
                    "u r logged out right now. ", "Exit",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            logoutSession();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is the inner class for the code, as you can see here

```
if (temp == exitButton) {
        if (s != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chatWindow,
                    "u r logged out right now. ", "Exit",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            logoutSession();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

the code will end the JVM anyway no matter what the default close operation is.
I am not using default close operation because:

```
f.setUndecorated(true);
```

I am not using the default "windows window theme"

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`setDefaultCloseOperation(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) command on the `JFrame`.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Will dispose of the frame, but the JVM will stay alive - unless all windows have been closed, as pointed out in the comment.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Will dispose of the frame and stop the JVM.

---

By default this is set to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: 1+ for using "dispose".  `Will dispose of the frame, but the JVM will stay alive.` yes, but, if the last frame is disposed, the JVM will stop (assuming no threads are running).

Comment: If you could take a look again, I am using frame.setUndecorated(true) so I have to create my own way of ending the GUI.

Comment: @NathanWithers you can just call `chatWindow.dispose();`. Make sure to set `chatWindow` to final so it can be accessed by the inner class.

Comment: for this do I need to create a chatWindow object? I'm not entirely sure how that works

Comment: @NathanWithers you already have one! Basically, `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` will effectively delegate to `dispose()` when one of the closing operations: ALT+F4, exit button, etc...; is performed.

Answer (score 0):

As you know you can create a JButton exit = new JButton with an exit Icon(yes to be nice...) and you can do:

1) `window.dispose()`(Released any source linked with the window)

2)or `window.setVisible(false)` just make the window(unvisible)

3)When you make a window(JFrame) you have the option to choose how it will respond(`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE,JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE,JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`

Gennerally the java programm will automatically `terminate`  if no windows are opened or just all the operation has finished(no loops running,etc)

*If you didn't used the **window.setUndecorated(false)** you could use Window Listener as follows:*

```
window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
   //This method is called when the X buttons is Clicked/Released
 }});
```

[Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)